# Alternativa ao Absolut Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Vi que o `AbsoluteLayout` foi descontinuado por questões de padrões em diferentes telefones. Uso atualmente o `RelativeLayout`, mas se por ele manter os objetos em posições relativas, se eu mudo um, o resto todo é alterado.

Existe algum substituto do `AbsoluteLayout` que deixe que eu mexa livremente nos componentes sem alterar a posição dos demais?

Comment: nem pense em usar layout absoluto. Com 500 mil telefones xinglings de diversos padrões de tela? E muitos deles não seguem padrões? Conheça o FrameLayout e seja feliz :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fala Gustavo,

Quando você usa o RelativeLayout, você deve especificar qual item fica em cima de qual, por exemplo:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_dias"
    android:text="Leonardo Dias"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_rotondo"
    android:text="Gustavo Rotondo"
    android:layout_below="@id/name_dias"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Eu tenho dois TextView, sendo que o Gustado Rotondo, ficará abaixo do Leonardo Dias.

E assim você vai controlando, existem outras opções também:

- android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name_dias" (esquerda)
- android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/name_dias" (direita)
- android:layout_above="@id/name_dias" (acima)

E você também pode usar o LinearLayout, quando você define ele, obrigatóriamente você deve especificar uma orientação, vertical ou horizontal, e os próprios items vão se encaixando:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Assim, todos os items vão se encaixando um abaixo do outro.

Espero ter conseguido explicar da melhor forma.

Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo, você pode continuar usando o `RelativeLayout` e setar a margem do componente para posicionar ele onde você quiser, é a única alternativa em relação ao `AbsoluteLayout` onde você fixava no lugar que queria.

Mas não é recomendado que você trabalhe com posições fixas de `view`, pois elas não serão posicionados do mesmo jeito em dispositivos com tamanhos de telas diferentes.